# Monitoring a google sheet for changes and validating data

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Problem: Write a program that creates a spreadsheet and constantly monitors it for changes. Any row that contains "invalid data" (according to a rule defined by a regex) in one of the columns should be deleted. For example, lets say that column A must be a valid date, while all the other columns can hold arbitrary data. Then, if someone enters an invalid date into cell A5, all the data in row 5 should be removed.

Attempted solution:
The program will have to deal with a lot of data, so when i am monitoring the sheet, i would like to obtain changes made to the spreadsheet as just the change. That is, i dont want to have to request the entire spreadsheet of data every time an edit is made. The only way that i have found to obtain only edits is through google apps script, but i have not found a way to create a spreadsheet along with an apps script bound to it. Is this possible through google apis, or is there a better way to tackle this problem?

I also looked into data validations as a possible solution, but I cannot find a setting that deletes an entire row when one specific column is invalid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a look at this guide to understand how to write a good question here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: One of the things you can try would be [onEdit simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) from Apps Script as this trigger fires evertyime an edit is made to a certain cell in your spreadsheet. Still, it would be better if you can show us what you've tried.